# Copying File using standard streams to a different location

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a method that copies a file to a folder that is local to my project. I am quite puzzled because from what I understand this should work. I decided to create a simple text file to test my copy file method but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
std::string newFile="Files\\newText.txt";

std::ifstream oldFile("C:\\Users\\dtruman\\Documents\\oldText.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
std::ofstream newTarget(newFile, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

char c;
while(oldFile.get(c));
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    newTarget.put(c);
}

newTarget.close();
oldFile.close();
```

Some of this stuff was me fiddling with the code. My problem is that no matter what I seem to do it never seems to copy the file over correctly, the contents of the new text file are always different then the original. Am I missing something, to my knowledge this block of code should work.

Comment: Interestingly you don't need a `while()` loop for this. As a special overload of `operator<<()` you can simply do this: `newTarget << oldFile.rdbuf();`. See: [operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) - case #2

Comment: I tried that earlier and for whatever reason that didn't work. What you see was the closest I could get to it actually copying over the file. And of course I have been working in my project all day and was completely oblivious to the semi-colon at the end of the while loop line. I had tried a couple different things before I got to this, I don't know why calling rdbuf() on the stream wasn't working but I'm not too concerned, as long as I get it to work, its a minor functionality in the application so I don't care about it as much.

Comment: Maybe its time to up the warning level of your compiler. On mine it would give a "suspicious semicolon" warning in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
while(oldFile.get(c));
```

consumes the entire file without any side effects due to the `;` at the end.

You need:

```
while(oldFile.get(c)) // Without the ;
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    newTarget.put(c);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I'm surprised I didn't catch that, that makes sense now since I was only grabbing the first character of the original file. Maybe I should take a break XD

Edit: It would actually be the last character not the first haha